# How do I change the color of the icons in europasscv?

Tags: color, europecv, icon, europasscv

I'm trying to create a CV in Latex using the europasscv document class. I've managed to change the color or the section and and highlights but I don't know how i can change the color of the icons from personalinfo section:

```
\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
```

I want to change the color from blue to something purple. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The europass is an official document in EU and should not be changed ...

Answer (score 1):

I think You shoul use `fontawesome package`, so You can easily choose color You need:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
 
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{electricpurple}{rgb}{0.75, 0.0, 1.0}%also You can find more colour here http://latexcolor.com/
\definecolor{darkpastelpurple}{rgb}{0.59, 0.44, 0.84}
\definecolor{lavenderpurple}{rgb}{0.59, 0.48, 0.71}
\definecolor{lightpastelpurple}{rgb}{0.69, 0.61, 0.85}
 
\begin{document}
    This is an example of colored icons:\\

    \textcolor{darkpastelpurple}{\faIcon[solid]{map-marker-alt}}\\

    \textcolor{electricpurple}{\faIcon[solid]{mobile-alt}}\\

    \textcolor{lavenderpurple}{\faIcon[solid]{github}}\\
    
    \textcolor{lightpastelpurple}{\faIcon[solid]{envelope}}\\
    
\end{document}
```